# Why does Google Chrome automatically redirect `http://app` to `https://app` but doesn't do that to `http://app2` or `http://napp`?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, https, http-redirect, hsts

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04.6 Desktop 64-bit
- Google Chrome `98.0.4758.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
- FireFox `92.0 (64-bit)`

What I did:

- Install `apache2` (so it starts a default local website that I can access at `http://localhost`).
- Edit `/etc/hosts` and add the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1   app
127.0.0.1   app2
127.0.0.1   napp
```

- On Google Chrome, open the following URIs:

  - `http://localhost`: Successfully opened the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" as an insecure domain.
  - `http://app`: **Got redirected to `https://app` automatically and returned the error "This site can’t be reached"**
  - `http://app2`: Same as `http://localhost`.
  - `http://napp`: Same as `http://localhost`.
- On FireFox, open the following URIs:

  - `http://localhost`: Successfully opened the "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" as an insecure domain.
  - `http://app`: **Same as `http://localhost`.**
  - `http://app2`: Same as `http://localhost`.
  - `http://napp`: Same as `http://localhost`.

I searched on Google and saw posts that talk about the automatic redirect from `http` to `https`, such as [*How to Stop Chrome from Automatically Redirecting to https*](https://howchoo.com/chrome/stop-chrome-from-automatically-redirecting-https). I followed the posts by deleting the security policy for the domain `app` and clearing the browser cache of all the time, **but I still got redirected from `http://app` to `https://app`**. (In fact, I was using a freshly installed OS and Google Chrome and had never opened **any** websites before doing the test.)

**Why does Google Chrome automatically redirect `http://app` to `https://app` but doesn't do that to `http://app2` or `http://napp`?**

I also learned that [*Chrome & Firefox now force `.dev` domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS*](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) and [*Google rolls out .app domains with built‑in HTTPS*](https://www.welivesecurity.com/2018/05/04/google-rolls-app-domain-built-https-tld/). So it looks like the browsers are using preloaded/builtin HSTS to enforce the use of `HTTPS`. **But does `http://app` count as a case of `.app` domain?**

I think it should be some browser settings because FireFox didn't do the redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, Chrome uses [a HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/) to automatically redirect certain domains from HTTP to HTTPS. This preload list is "a list of sites that are **hardcoded** into Chrome as being HTTPS only." `app` is already included into this preload list, as shown by [this link](https://hstspreload.org/?domain=app): "Status: app is currently preloaded." Therefore, when `http://app` is entered, Chrome automatically redirects it to `https://app`. But `app2` and `napp` are not included, so `http://app2` and `http://napp` are untouched.

I wrote the article [*Why does Google Chrome automatically redirect `http://app` to `https://app` but doesn't do that to `http://app2` or `http://napp`?*](https://yaobinwen.github.io/2022/02/18/Google-Chrome-http-app.html) to explain this with more details and other related links.

Comment: I am trying to access web dev `port 3000` from my phone to a local server in my PC connected to the same Wifi network. It always worked. But no longer works. The **page does show up for a split second** and then  **instaltly redirects** to `https` which as it is local server, gives SSL errors.  I tried on `chrome Mobile`, `Fireforx mobile` same `SSL ERROR`.